# Memory consumed by persistent index

Tags: memory-management, arangodb

We are using arangodb 3.1.3 for our project and we have created a collection with 1GB of data.

When we uploaded the data without creating persistent index for the attributes in the document, the memory consumed by the indexes as shown in the web console is 225.4 MB of memory.

When we uploaded the data by creating a persistent index for one of the attributes which is present in all the documents, the memory size was still the same. We assumed that the persistent index would consume more memory. But it did not.

How should we measure the memory size in Arangodb especially index memory ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get the index's size through arangodbsh, as in:

```
db.[collectionName].figures()
```

There's another SO question similar this, but I can't seem to find it now.